# Structuring Mocha test with objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Trying to learn some js and mocha and am sure im doing something fundamentally wrong.  For example:

Product model:

```
var Product = function (sku) {
    this.sku = sku;
};

Product.prototype.getSku = function() {
    return this.sku;
}

module.exports = {Product: Product};
```

and my tests:

```
var productLib = require('../../model/Product.js');
var assert = require('assert')

describe("Product", function() {
    describe('#getSku()', function() {

        var product = new productLib.Product('test_sku');
        it('should have an getSku method', function() {
            assert.equal(typeof product.getSku, 'function');
        });
        it('should return the loaded sku', function() {
            assert.equal(product.getSku(), 'test_sku');
        });
    });
});
```

Is this correct in terms of how the product model is structured and exported?  It seems wrong but i had to do it this way so that in the test I could do:

```
var product = new productLib.Product('test_sku');
```

and have the assertion that the sku was set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with how you're setting up your module if that's what you're asking. The only thing that I see that you could possibly change might be how you export your Product model:

From this:

```
module.exports = {Product: Product};
```

To this:

```
module.exports = Product;
```

Which you would just use like so:

```
var ProductModel = require('../../model/Product');
var model = new ProductModel(...);
```